# Upload video to Vimeo in Android

Tags: java, android, vimeo-api, vimeo-android

I need to upload video to Vimeo. Can anyone suggest any SDK or library which would help me do that successfully?

Answer (score 2):

The Vimeo Networking library you are referring to does not support upload; a separate upload library will be released at a later date. In order to upload you will need to the API https://developer.vimeo.com/api/upload/videos.

Vimeo upload code for all platform : https://github.com/vimeo

Answer (score 1):

The various libraries to interact with he **Vimeo** API are listed here: https://developer.vimeo.com/api/libraries

Looks like you are developing for **Android**, this is the official one in Java:
https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo-networking-java

Comment: thanks jrbedard ..
I want the upload task in vimeo i got the access token using above demo  project

Comment: I have tried Java Vimeo API 3.0 by clickntap demo mentioned in https://developer.vimeo.com/api/libraries ,but for large videos it takes too long to upload. Please help me out !!